# Wrong presenting view controller if presented from an over-current-context view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller

So I'm having an issue with 3 view controllers I have. I have View Controller A which presents a View Controller B with a presentation style of `currentContext`. This View Controller B presents a View Controller C with the default presentation style. Something like this:

      `presents over current context         presents regularly
VC A -------------------------------> VC B --------------------> VC C`

The problem is, when I want to dismiss the View Controller C, the `presentingViewController` property points to VC A instead of VC B, and also, the `viewWillAppear` of VC B is not called, while the `viewWillAppear` in  VC A is.

I cannot use the completion block of `dismiss(animated flag: Bool, 
  completion: (() -> Void)? = nil)` because VC B doesn't have control over the dismissal of VC C. It is a flow that can be started from several points in the app, so the management of the navigation of this flow is done in a separate class.

What is happening here? I really need the `viewWillAppear` of VC B to be called.

Comment: Would you be willing to post the code for the 3 view controllers. It will be hard to help you without it.

Answer (score 0):

@Kinopio - I guess the problem you are facing is because you are dismissing the controller from VC A, so here self point to current class. You need to pass the message to VC B and that dismiss from there.

Like

```
//code in VC A
func dismissViewControllerNoC(){
 viewControllerNoB.dismiss()
}

//code in VC B
func dismiss(){
dismiss(animated flag: Bool, 
  completion: (() -> Void)? = nil)
}
```